# How to pass space separated arguments to run() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> from subprocess import PIPE,run
>>> cmd="ls"
>>> args="-l -r -t"
>>> run([cmd,args])
ls: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
CompletedProcess(args=['ls', '-l -r -t'], returncode=2)

>>> args='-l'
>>> run([cmd,args]) #Now works

>>> args='-l'
>>> args2='-r'
>>> run([cmd,args,args2]) #Works too.
```

I use a script in place of `ls` and some arguments in place of `-l -r -t`, and I see similar error thrown out by the script.

I get the arguments in a variable and may have spaces, it will have to get passed to the script as is, how can I do this?

Comment: What is that `run` function? Did you do `from subprocess import *`, or are you using one of the third-party shell wrapper libraries, or…?

Comment: `run([cmd] + args.split())`

Comment: @OferSadan, please don't suggest that -- it's inherently quite broken if you ever wanted to pass something containing literal whitespace, and giving the user explicit/literal control with nothing getting in the way is a big chunk of the *point* of passing an explicit argv; when you put `shlex.split()` in the loop, suddenly there's an extra layer again between what the programmer writes and what's actually invoked.

Comment: That's why I didn't write a full answer, it'll work in this specific case only, but should hint at what's wrong here

Comment: @rodee, wrt. "passed to the script as-is", when you run a program in UNIX, you don't pass it a single string with all its arguments, you pass it a *list*; that's how it works at the underlying operating system layer. See `man execve` for the underlying OS-level syscall. Thus, anything that you pass a string has to split that string up to make a list before it can start your actual program. Thus, you have the most control (and least chance of unexpected data -- ie. names with spaces -- causing bugs) by just making it an explicit list in the first place yourself.

Comment: ...when someone calls `system("ls -l -r -t")` in C, for example, that in turn calls `["/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l -r -t"]`, and then `/bin/sh` invokes something like `["/bin/ls", "-l", "-r", "-t"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `run` is [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), you can't pass it an executable plus an argument string; you can only pass it a list of arguments, or, if you're using `shell=True`, a command line string—either way, the list or string has to include the executable.

Normally, the right way to do that is to use a list in the first place:

```
cmd = 'ls'
args = [cmd, '-l', '-r', '-t']
run(args)
```

---

If you're looking for a way to do things conveniently from the interactive interpreter, it might be reasonable to do what you're asking.

In that case, you'll want to use [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to split the arguments.

And you'll want to write a wrapper that takes care of things for you. Instead of `from subprocess import run`, just `import subprocess`, then do this:

```
def run(cmd, argstring, *args, **kwargs):
    cmdargs = [cmd] + shlex.split(argstring)
    return subprocess.run(cmdargs, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

However, in that case, you may want to look into using a more advanced Python interactive interpreter, like IPython/Jupyter, or using one of the fancy shell wrapper libraries off PyPI, or both.

For example, using [`shell`](https://pypi.org/project/shell/) (which I've never used before, but came up in a search and looked nifty):

```
>>> from shell import shell
>>> cmd = shell('ls -l -r -t')
>>> print(cmd.output())
['total 11040',
 'drwxr-xr-x@   9 andrewbarnert  staff      288 Oct 26  2009 python-0.9.1',
# ...
```

Or, even more simply, from IPython:

```
In  [1]: !ls -l -r -t
total 11040
drwxr-xr-x@   9 andrewbarnert  staff      288 Oct 26  2009 python-0.9.1
# ...
```

(And you can read up on IPython %magic commands if you want to capture that output instead of just see it.)